# Kotlin Gson cast json to hierarchical class object

Tags: kotlin, gson

I read the response of API, which return a JSON object like this

```
{
    "companies": [{
        "id": 9,
        "label": "Name A"
    }, {
        "id": 13,
        "label": "Name B"
    }, {
        "id": 14,
        "label": "Name C"
    }],
    "types": [{
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Music"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Theater"
    }],
    "shows": [{
        "id": 1,
        "company": 9,
        "label": "Label XX",
        "type": 1
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "company": 13,
        "label": "Label YY",
        "type": 1
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "company": 14,
        "label": "Label ZZ",
        "type": 2
    }]
}
```

I have many class

```
class ReponseApi {
    lateinit var companies: List<Company>
    lateinit var types: List<TypeShow>
    lateinit var shows: List<Show>
}

class Company {
    var id:Int = 0
    lateinit var label:String
}

class TypeShow {
    var id:Int = 0
    lateinit var label:String
}

class Show {
    var id:Int = 0
    lateinit var company: Company
    lateinit var label:String
    lateinit var type: TypeShow
}
```

And finally the Gson().fromJson associated

```
val apiData = Gson().fromJson(strResponse, ReponseApi::class.java)
```

I have the following error :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1
```

I understand that Kotlin cannot make the link between a "Company" object with id 9 and a "Show" object having property "company" and a Int value "9".

I tried something like build an array of "Company", and find the good one in constructor function in "Show" class, but... i think there is an easier and cleaner way to do this.

I think i need a TypeAdapter in fromJson but i'm stuck with the correct syntax to use.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think there is an easier or more automatic way. You have to resolve relations between objects by yourself. But in practice it should be just a few lines of code, so not a big deal. Also, I suggest separating classes for data in transit and for processing by your application internally.